# CVS remove sticky tag from directory without update other files

Tags: cvs

I have a tree structure in CVS where I have to add a few new files
the old files have been checked-out with a tag

so when I try to add a new file:

```
C:\MyFolder> cvs add MyNewFile.txt
cvs add: cannot add file on non-branch tag MyTag
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Why don't you just check out your branch, add the files, then return to the sticky tag? That really is the most sensible thing to do.
2. If you insist on doing it your way, you could try just editing that directory's `CVS/Tag` file to remove the sticky tag. Add your files, then change the `CVS/Tag` file back. (You'll have to make sure you're in the directory in question when doing the CVS operations and specify the exact files, not recursive operation.)

Comment: I ended up doing 1.